# Найти главные члены

Tags: сказуемые, члены-предложения, подлежащее

Есть в дикой роще, у оврага, зеленый холм. Там вечно тень.

Comment: @Yil, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Ответ удален. Здесь не делают домашние задания. Предложите свой вариант, а мы поправим, если будет неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

Есть в дикой роще, у оврага, зеленый холм. Что? - холм. Что о нём говорится? - что он есть. Холм-подлежащее, есть-сказуемое.

Там вечно тень. Что? - тень. Что о ней говорится? - что она там. Подразумеваем, что она там есть. - неполное предложение с пропуском сказуемого ЕСТЬ, эллипсис. Значит, здесь только подлежащее с подразумеваемым сказуемым.

О наличии сказуемого говорит присутствие обстоятельства ТАМ. Если есть обстоятельство - есть и сказуемое, но в данном случае нулевое, пропущенное.